# Lync messenger on server

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2007, lync, lync-server-2010

I know for the share point development there is need for lync chat installed into the
all client machine. But is there any configuration that LYNC is into the server .. and clients can access it without downloading it into the each client machine.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: U got any answer for this

Answer (score 0):

You need to install Lync servers. Lync is not so easy to install, so you need a qualified person.
Lync has a web client. No need to install. It is not complete, but maybe enough for your needs.
You can contact me via fisil.com if you need more help.